# Слетели переводы в справке про Очереди проверок (или просто новые тексты)

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, справка

И сами статьи под ссылками без переводов. [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В последнее время слетело очень много переводов. На столько много, что я уже на мету перестал писать (пропадает перевод буквально у пары предложений и в многих местах)

Comment: @Зонтик советую всё же репортить, так больше вероятность исправить это быстрее.

Comment: А переводы вообще были? Когда я в первый раз открыл справку, то видел, что там изначально этих переводов не было.

Comment: последним пунктом на скриншоте идёт статья [Что такое очереди проверок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro). и там до сих пор упоминается очередь первых сообщений, которой уже нет, а вместо неё есть две других — первых ответов и первых вопросов.